# Is apple will reject my iPad app if i will not use Split view in my application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uisplitview

I have make an iphone app and now i am converting it to universal app for ipad.
I want that interface of my looks similar in ipohne and in ipad.

If i will not using the split view controller for iPad then is apple will reject my app for iPad.

Is it compulsory to use split view in iPad?

Answer (score 2):

No there are LOTS of applications that do not use split view !

Answer (score 1):

of course not !
Where have you seen that split view is mandatory ?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not required at all. I have submitted my app without split view.

Answer (score 0):

No there are lot of apps in itune where ipad does not need splite view.You can check apps in itunes.like : singing diasis,DFW and routeone..